# Wordpress - permalinks not returning any data after PHP CURL scrape

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, curl

I was wondering if any users would be able to share some information/thought on my current issue. I am working on a Wordpress website, I've tested this on localhost, and webserver, so I know the PHP code works fine - however, when clicking on a time (see http://www.punter2pro.com/racecards) it follows the URL correctly,but the PHP script is not fired? Is this an issue with .htaccess or permalinks?

This is a copy of the .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: have you updated your permalinks to use the same as your dev site? They look like the standard setting.